# DataGridView ComboBox Cell Causes Program to Crash

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, datagridviewcomboboxcell, crash

I have a datagridview that contains 6 columns and 50 rows, one of the columns is a datagridview combobox. In the collection property of the datagridview in the designer I have entered all of the items in the combobox. When clicking on the cell as the first thing within the datagrid it works fine and the collection is populated properly within the combobox.

**The problem:**
The problem occurs when I enter information into a different cell (text) and then leave the cell and move over to the combobox. It causes the program to crash, no exceptions or anything. The program crashes in the debugger. My question is has anyone seen this crash before, and if so how did you work around it or fix it.

**Debugger Crash Information:**

Problem signature: 
  Problem Event Name:       APPCRASH 
  Application Name:     Client.exe
  Application Version:      1.0.1.0
  Application Timestamp:    51825708
  Fault Module Name:        StackHash_69d8
  Fault Module Version:     6.1.7601.17725
  Fault Module Timestamp:   4ec49b60
  Exception Code:       c0000374
  Exception Offset:     000c380b
  OS Version:               6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.1
  Locale ID:                1033
  Additional Information 1: 69d8
  Additional Information 2: 69d8f202107dcd312c72fa82cc714206
  Additional Information 3: 917d
  Additional Information 4: 917d990ad144e90eed233698961d2c73

**ComboBox Values:**
Travel - Air
Travel - Rental Car
Travel - Taxi, Bus, Limo
Travel - Rental Car Fuel
Travel - Parking/Tolls
Travel - Personal Car Mileage
Travel - Internet
Lodging - Room & Tax Only
Personal - Breakfast
Personal - Lunch
Personal - Dinner
Entertainment
Office Supplies
Equipment
Software
Computer
Dues & Subscriptions
Postage
Company - Breakfast Activity
Company - Lunch Activity
Company - Dinner Activity

Comment: Do you have some code for your datagridView?

Comment: I would provide code, however the error doesn't occur within my code. I built a new datagridview with a combobox and I'm getting the same problem, so I don't think it's the properties.

I'll get some screenshots

Comment: Bad news bears, I can't post screenshots until I get 10 reputation points...time to get busy

Comment: You don't have any cell events that code is firing on?  what values do you have in the comboBox?  What are you typing into the cell?  I just created a datagridview with a text field and a comboBox, and I am able to interact with it as expected...

Comment: I have no code associated with any of the cell events or datagridview events. 

I entered the values in the designer, in the cells collection property. I added those values to the main post. I'll try building another form and trying again.

Comment: Exception Code 0xc0000374 is STATUS_HEAP_CORRUPTION.  Check out the following link for potential fixes.   http://www.faultwire.com/solutions-exception_core/Error-0xC0000374-*1747.html